# Orbits of $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb F_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$ be the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices over field $\Bbb F_2$, and $G \subset X$ be the group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb F_2$

Let $G$ act on $X$ by $g*x = gxg^{-1}$

Need to find the orbits of $X$ under this action.

Computing for each $x \in X$ would require $6 \times 16 =96$ calculations...What is a quicker way to obtain the distinct orbits?

Comment: What are some of your observations?  Are there special cases that make the partitioning of $X$ into orbits easy?  Are there some properties that all matrices in an orbit must share?  Partitioning the sixteen matrices into orbits should go pretty quickly once you find a few orbits; those matrices are taken into account and don't need to be computed again.

Comment: @hardmath ok, thanks for reminding me that the orbits partition $X$ :) (I should know this if I had read my notes more carefully! and the fact that the orbits either do not intersect or are identical). So once I've noticed that the orbits I've computed cover $X$ I can stop computing lol. This shouldn't take long as you said

Comment: Note that the group action (similarity) involves $|G|=6$, so sizes of orbits have to divide six.  There are a couple of obvious singleton orbits, and similarity preserves rank.  So you might want to start with a random matrix in $X$ that has rank one, just to see how big its orbit is.  Finally, transpose will either give the same orbit or a "mirror image".